# CAPTCHA on custom form

Tags: 7, captcha

I have a client where they have an integrated form from another website.  For some reason the Drupal 7 captcha module will not work on this form when entering it into captcha settings.  The form id="contact-form" and then in the captcha setting I put contact_form.  This works on any other form that is either created with webform or and drupal module but will not work when the custom form is put into the content section of the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You must create form with FormAPI, then the form is avalable for Captcha as you say "contact-form" -> "contact_form". If the form is embeded whatever other method like iframe, then the form must already contain integrated own captcha. This also applies when form is build without FormAPI - using  in client's site.